# Comparing old and new value of the same variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, compare, var

I coded a website using Ajax and I want to compare clicked links to avoid page reloading.
My way to do it is having a var called `Link` and storing url into it.
Everytime I click on the `#button`, the url is stored into the Link,
then I call the `CompareLink()` function, then the `GoToLink()` function.

```
var Link;

$('#button').click(function() {
    Link = http://myurl ;
    CompareLink();
    GoToLink();
}
```

I have trouble with the data comparison. I want to compare the OLD value of `Link` with the new Value, so I wrote a very vague approach (nonworking) and I wanted to know if somebody could help me.

```
function CompareLink() {
    if ( Link == .data(Link)) {
        //execute code
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this?

```
<a href='something here' class='button' >something</a>
<a href='something else here' class='button' >something else</a>​


var link = null, oldLink = null;
$('.button').click(function() {
    link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (oldLink == null) {
         oldLink = link;
    }
    CompareLink(link, oldLink);
    return false;
}
```

and then

```
function CompareLink(link, oldLink) {
    if ( link == oldLink) {
        // do something now
    }

    oldLink = link;
}

function GoToLink(link) {
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

checkout this fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/V9DyW/

Comment: It's not working, because the 'something' is the previous data, stored in Link, and it changes everytime I click on another link

Comment: Great Job
I started to create my own solution but yours works too !
Thank you Rorchakh

Comment: I Can't vote up yet, but thanks for the time you spent creating de jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {}
var count = 0;
data['name' + count++] = "value1" -> name1
data['name' + count++] = "value2" -> name2
```

***get old value***

```js
data['name' + (count - 1)] ->  'value1'
```

Comment: Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).